# How to write mysql query to achieve the following type of join (Join based on value of a column )

Tags: mysql, database, join

**Table users:**

```
id----email 
1-----s@s.com 
2-----p@p.com
```

**Table user_buddies**

```
id-----user_id----buddy_id----status enum('accepted','pending') 
1------1----------2-----------pending
```

Suppose I am querying with respect to user 2 then I want to get user 2 email. If I am querying with respect to user 1 then I want to get user 1 email.

The below query is always returning empty rows.

```
SELECT
    users.email,
    ub1.*, ub2.*
FROM
    users
JOIN user_buddies ub1 ON users.id = ub1.user_id
JOIN user_buddies ub2 ON users.id = ub2.buddy_id
WHERE
    users.id = 1;
```

Can anyone please help me in this?
Thank you.

**Expected result:**

```
email-----user_id-----buddy_id-----status
s@s.com --1-----------2------------pending (If queryed on user 2)
p@p.com---1-----------2------------pending (If queried on user 1)
```

**Context:**

When `user1` sends request to `user2` **only one row is added** to the `user_buddies` table with `status=pending`. So, both for `user1` and `user2` buddy list is created using same row. So if queried against `user2` email needed is `user2's`.

Comment: Please share your expected output in tabular form

Comment: And check this query whether it meets your need: `SELECT
 users.email,
  ub1.*
FROM users
JOIN user_buddies ub1 ON users.id = ub1.user_id
WHERE users.id = 1;`

Comment: And because of the SECOND JOIN `JOIN user_buddies ub2 ON users.id = ub2.buddy_id` you are getting empty result set.

Comment: Ultimately what I want to achieve is, 
Suppose id = 2.
user1 has sent request to user2. Status pending.
user2 wants the list of buddies he has. Even the row with status pending is shown to user2 with user1's email.

Comment: I need to check both user_id and buddy_id while listing buddies. 
If users.id is buddy_id for a specific user, then he should accept the request.

Comment: what if one user has multiple buddies? Then do you want a single row for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the following query:

```
SELECT
    users.email,
    ub1.user_id,
    ub1.buddy_id,
    ub1.`status`
FROM
    users
JOIN user_buddies ub1 ON users.id = ub1.user_id OR users.id = ub1.buddy_id
WHERE   users.id = 2;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed8a27/1/0)

**Result:**

```
email      user_id     buddy_id     status
p@p.com       1           2         pending (if queried on users.id = 2)
s@s.com       1           2         pending (if queried on users.id = 1)
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            u.email
        FROM users u
        WHERE   u.id =
        IF (
            users.id = ub1.user_id,
            ub1.buddy_id,
            ub1.user_id
        )
    ) AS buddyEmail,
    ub1.user_id,
    ub1.buddy_id,
    ub1.`status`
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN user_buddies ub1 ON users.id = ub1.user_id
OR users.id = ub1.buddy_id
WHERE   users.id = 2;
```

[**Check this fiddle of this new query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed8a27/3/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But,
If user.id = 2 and user_buddies.buddy_id  = 2 and id status = pending, email should be of user1. 
Whole funda is if user1 i s accessing the recored, he should get buddy's email.
In the above example, if users.id is 2 then email returned should be s@s.com.

Comment: I've given the answer based on your context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. 
But is there a way to get this way?
If users.id is 1 then get email of the user.id = user_buddies.buddy_id.
I mean how to get buddy's email. Both are buddies. User1 and user2. But when user one checks, he should get user2's email and vice versa.
Can you please help me in achieving this?

Comment: Sorry dude. Aloof from my work station. I will provide it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Forgot to add the fiddle of the new query. Just added. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Userid' querysource, u.id, u.email, ub.*, u1.EMAIL AS Buddyemail
FROM @users u 
JOIN @user_buddies ub ON u.id = ub.user_id
JOIN @users u1 ON u1.id = ub.BUDDY_ID
WHERE u.id = 1

UNION

SELECT 'Buddyidid', u.id, u.email, ub.*, u1.email AS Buddyemail
FROM @users u 
JOIN @user_buddies ub ON u.id = ub.buddy_id 
JOIN @users u1 ON u1.id = ub.user_ID
WHERE u.id = 1
```